# Animating a class that is an extension of UIView in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to get an instance of my Options class to animate onto the screen using the function `appear()` which activates when pressing a button in my `SearchResult` class but I'm having trouble, the instance has been added as a subview to the view in the `ViewController` Class.

I've been able to use the function `optionMenu.appear()` in `ViewController` and that works as it should but not when it's called through clicking the button in `SearchResult`, it seems to do everything but the animation as I've tested printing in `optionMenu.appear()` and it successfully prints.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SearchResult {

    private let link: String

    var body = UIView()

    init(_ link: String){

        self.link = link

        let options = UIButton(x: Int(body.bounds.width-60), y: 10, size: 50.0)
        options.addTarget(self, action: #selector(optionsClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        body.addSubview(options)

    }

    @objc func optionsClicked(){
        ViewController().optionMenu.appear()
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Options: UIView{

    var buttons = [UIButton]()
    private var link = String()

    init(_ titles: [String]){
        let height = ((titles.count+1)*65)+5
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.height)-height, width: Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width), height: height))
        var i = 0
        for title in titles{
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 5+(i*65), width: Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)-10, height: 60))
            button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
            buttons.append(button)
            self.addSubview(button)
            i += 1
        }
        let cancel = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 5+(i*65), width: Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)-10, height: 60))
        cancel.setTitle("cancel", for: .normal)
        self.addSubview(cancel)        
    }

    func appear(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -self.bounds.height)
        })
    }

    @objc func disappear(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        })
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand that `ViewController().optionMenu.appear` does not talk to the ViewController on the screen? It just creates a new ViewController and then throws it away. You might want to read http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Comment: thanks matt, link helped a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are constructing a new Viewcontroller, and calling appear on that Viewcontroller's option menu every time `optionsClicked()` is called.  You need a reference to the viewController that has the option menu and do `myViewController.optionMenu.appear()`